# Python: confused with classes, attributes and methods in OOP

Tags: python, oop, methods

I'm learning Python OOP now and confused with somethings in the code below.

Questions:

1. `def __init__(self, radius=1):`
   What does the argument/attribute "radius = 1" mean exactly? 
   Why isn't it just called "radius"?
2. The method area() has no argument/attribute "radius".
   Where does it get its "radius" from in the code?
   How does it know that the radius is 5?

   ```
   class Circle:
       pi = 3.141592

       def __init__(self, radius=1):
           self.radius = radius 

       def area(self):
           return self.radius * self.radius * Circle.pi

       def setRadius(self, radius):
           self.radius = radius

       def getRadius(self):
           return self.radius

   c = Circle()

   c.setRadius(5)
   ```

Also,

1. In the code below, why is the attribute/argument `name` missing in the brackets?
2. Why was is not written like this: `def __init__(self, name)`
   and `def getName(self, name)`?

   ```
   class Methods:
       def __init__(self):
           self.name = 'Methods'

       def getName(self):
           return self.name
   ```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. "`setRadius`"? Really!? If you took the code from some book/tutorial, stop reading it RIGHT NOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, radius=1):
    self.radius = radius
```

This is default value setting to initialize a variable for the class scope.This is to avoid any garbage output in case some user calls `c.Area()` right after `c = Circle()`.

```
In the code below, why is the attribute/argument "name" missing in the brackets?
```

In the line `self.name = 'Methods'` you are creating a variable `name` initialized to string value `Methods`.

> Why was is not written like this: def init(self, name) and def
>   getName(self, name)?

`self.name` is defined for the class scope. You can get and set its value anywhere inside the class.

Answer (score 8):

The `def method(self, argument=value):` syntax defines a *keyword argument*, with a default value. Using that argument is now optional, if you do not specify it, the default value is used instead. In your example, that means `radius` is set to `1`.

Instances are referred to, within a method, with the `self` parameter. The `name` and `radius` values are stored *on* `self` as attributes (`self.name = 'Methods'` and `self.radius = radius`) and can later be retrieved by referring to that named attribute (`return self.name`, `return self.radius * self.radius * Circle.pi`).

I can heartily recommend you follow the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/), it'll explain all this and more.

Comment: Thanks, I don't use the Python Tutorial Handbook because it is only theory with no examples. I am a person who learns by examples.

Comment: @user1586038: The tutorial is *full* of examples.

Comment: But if you want to find one that suits your needs better, there is a wealth of links available for you, starting at http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0):

1. The syntax `radius = 1` specifies a parameter "radius" which has a default value of `1`:

   > > > def my_func(param=1):
   > > >       ...     print(param)
   > > >       ... 
   > > >       my_func()  #uses the default value
   > > >       1
   > > >       my_func(2)  #uses the value passed
   > > >       2

Note that in python there exists more kinds of parameters: positional and keyword parameters, or both.

Usually parameters can be assigned both using the positional notation and the keyword:

```
>>> def my_func(a,b,c):
...     print (a,b,c)
... 
>>> my_func(1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)
>>> my_func(1,2,c=3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

1. Python uses "explicit" instance passing, so the first `self` parameter is used to pass the instance on which the methods are called. You can think of `self` as being the `this` of Java. But you must always use it to access instance attributes/methods. You can't call just `area()`, you must say `self.area()`.

When you do `self.attribute = 1` you create a new attribute `attribute` with value `1` and assign it to the instance `self`. So in the `area()` method `self.radius` refers to the `radius` attribute of the `self` instance.

The `__init__` method is a special method. It's something similar to a constructor.
It is called when you instantiate the class. Python has a lot of these "special methods", for example the method `__add__(self, other)` is called when using the operator `+`.